# Memory leak in MPI_File_read_at

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, io, mpi

i'm writing a C/MPI program that making many processes read from a data file. 
When using the standard functions from stdio (fopen, fread, fseek) everything goes well. The problem that i can't go beyond 4 Go offsets. So i used MPI-IO functions to read a big file and at this moment memory doesn't liberate well.

In fact i read a buffer, i process it then i free the allocated memory. The memory usage per process is perfect but the global memory usage doesn't stop increasing. I don't have this problem by just replacing mpi_file_read at by fread.

there is my code :

```
double CPUtime(){ return ((double) clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;}int main(int argc, char* argv []){

if(argc != 5) {
    printf("\t[Dictionary file] [Dictionary] [Input file] [Buffer size]\n");
    exit(0);
}

char* sInput    = malloc (sizeof(char)*maxLength);
char* sOutput   = malloc (sizeof(char)*maxLength);
char* compl     = malloc (sizeof(char)*maxLength);

char* sDictionaryFileName   =   argv[1];
char* sDictionaryName       =   argv[2];
char* filename              =   argv[3];
int Mbuffer                 =   atoi(argv[4]);



int maxBuffer = Mbuffer*1024*1024;
int over      = 10000;

int rank,numprocess;
long int offset;


char* buffer;
char* opbuffer;

double tstart=CPUtime();

MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );

/* mpi version */
/* open the file*/
MPI_File fh;
int err;
err = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, filename, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
if (err != MPI_SUCCESS) {
    char errstr[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING];
    int  errlen;
    MPI_Error_string(err, errstr, &errlen);
    printf("Error at opening file %s (%s)\n",filename,errstr);
    MPI_Finalize();
    exit(1);
}

// get offsets and buffer size
MPI_Offset sfile;
MPI_File_get_size(fh,&sfile);
MPI_Status status;


/* C version */
/*FILE* fh;
long int sfile;
fh =fopen( filename,"rb");
if (fh==NULL) {
    printf("Error at opening file %s\n",filename);
    exit(1);
}
// get offsets and buffer size
fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_END);
sfile = ftell(fh);
fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_SET);*/


MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocess );

/* number of iterations */
long int data_size = (long int)(sfile/(numprocess));
int nbIter = data_size/maxBuffer;
if(nbIter<=1){
    nbIter = 1;
    maxBuffer = data_size;
}

/* offsets */
offset = data_size*(rank);
long int cursor = offset;
char* header;
if(rank==0){
    FILE* fh;
    fh =fopen( filename,"rb");
    if (fh==NULL) {
        printf("Error at opening file %s\n",filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    /* read the header and broadcast it */
    header = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    fgets(header,1000,fh);
    fclose(fh);

    //broadcast header
    int sndHeader = strlen(header);
    //cursor+=sndHeader;
    int process_counter;
    for(process_counter=1;process_counter<numprocess;process_counter++){
        int ierr = MPI_Send(&sndHeader, 1, MPI_INT, process_counter, 42,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if (ierr != MPI_SUCCESS) {
            int errclass,resultlen;
            char err_buffer[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING];
            MPI_Error_class(ierr,&errclass);
            if (errclass== MPI_ERR_RANK) {
                fprintf(stderr,"Invalid rank used in MPI send call\n");
                MPI_Error_string(ierr,err_buffer,&resultlen);
                fprintf(stderr,err_buffer);
                MPI_Finalize();
            }
        }
        MPI_Send(header, sndHeader, MPI_CHAR, process_counter, 43, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
else{
    /* receive the header */
    int sizeofHeader;
    MPI_Status s ;
    MPI_Recv(&sizeofHeader,1,MPI_INT,0,42,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&s);
    header = malloc (sizeof(char)*sizeofHeader+1);
    MPI_Recv(header,sizeofHeader,MPI_CHAR,0,43,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&s);
}


/* Synchronization barrier */
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);


int count;

opbuffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*maxBuffer);

/* C version */
//fseek(fh,cursor,SEEK_SET);

for(count=0;count<nbIter;count++){

    if(count==0 && rank==numprocess-1){ //init ring
        //send the token to p0
        int token=1;
        MPI_Send(&token,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,0,55,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    //recv
    int token;
    int sender;
    if(rank==0)
        sender = numprocess-1;
    else
        sender=rank-1;

    MPI_Status s;
    MPI_Recv(&token,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,sender,55,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&s);
    fflush(stdout);printf("P%d got the token at %G\n",rank,CPUtime());
    //read
    double start=CPUtime();
    /*double readtime;
    double sread=CPUtime();//read time*/

    //read
    if(token==1){
        /* MPI version */
        int err=MPI_File_read_at(fh, cursor,opbuffer,  sizeof(char)*maxBuffer, MPI_CHAR, &status);
        if(err!=MPI_SUCCESS){
            /*char errstr[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING];
            int  errlen;
            MPI_Error_string(err, errstr, &errlen);
            printf("Error reading file %s (%s)\n",filename,errstr);*/
            MPI_Finalize();
            exit(0);
        }

        /* C version of read */
        /*int k=fread(opbuffer,sizeof(char),maxBuffer,fh);
        if(k==0)
            perror("fread");*/

        cursor+=maxBuffer;
        buffer=opbuffer;

    }
    else{
        printf("Error token!\n");
        token=1;
    }
    //printf("P%d readtime=%G\n",rank,CPUtime()-sread);
    //Isend
    int next = (rank+1)%numprocess;
    MPI_Send(&token,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,next,55,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /* start processing*/ 
    /* end processing */


}
free(opbuffer);
int er=MPI_File_close(&fh);
if(er!=MPI_SUCCESS){
    printf("Error closing file\n");
    MPI_Finalize();
    exit(1);
}
MPI_Finalize();

printf("Global time : %G\n",CPUtime()-tstart);
return 0;
}
```

If any one have any idea of what is it i would apprciate that.
Thank you.

Comment: Now I haven't used mpi but you don't seem to provide enough code. However for each time you run the for-loop you will allocate memory on the stack, is this a necessity? Instead of declaring the variables outside of the loop and reuse them. Second thing, probably unrelated to the problem: you don't clear your structs (I assume MPI_Status etc is a struct) before you use them, which most likely leads to that they contain garbage before you write to them (and if you don't fill them completely).

Comment: @Jite thank you for your reply. in fact i'm doing the allocation only one before starting the loop and i free after the loop. There is a big thing before the loop because i just open the file and calculate the offsets. I will see about Status maybe it's the reasonfor that memory leaks

Comment: It would have been nice to at least share with us what MPI library you are using, together with the exact version. On the other hand, most Unixes support large files if you define something like `__USE_LARGEFILE64` before you include `stdio.h`.

Comment: Yes i'm sorry i'm using MPICH2-1.4.1p1 on a windows envirment. I can use the MSDN functions to handle a 64bit integer offset but i hoped that i can use MPI parallel IO. If the i can't resolve the memory leaks issue i will be obliged to use 2 versions one for windows and one  for linux.

Comment: Are you sure it is really a memory leak and not the OS couting file mappings possibly used by the MPI-IO implementation to do I/O as user memory? I am not sure how MPICH2 does its MPI-IO but I know that at least Open MPI uses ROMIO that has certain optimised operations for several different known file systems. E.g. ROMIO uses `ReadFile()` with overlapped I/O on NTFS but it reads in the user supplied buffer, so no memory should ever leak.

Comment: @HristoIliev i think that is the problem. MPICH2 seems to allocate temporary memory for buffering in the user memory so the OS can't uses it. That  explain the fact that none of my processes or any other process in the Task Manager has the memory usage increasing. I'm wondering why a similiar problem is not present in formums.

Comment: No, it's not. I've taken a look at the source code of MPICH2 1.4.1p1. It uses the same ROMIO library as Open MPI does. The implementation of `MPI_File_read_at()` does _not_ allocate additional buffers - neither the generic version nor the NTFS optimised one. It only reads into the user-supplied buffer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13772/discussion-between-ezzakrem-and-hristo-iliev)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that you're never calling `MPI_File_close`. That will cause intermediate operations on the file to leak. Note that you should also close it under the error condition `if(err!=MPI_SUCCESS)` if you really want to write clean code.

Comment: i added the close instruction but it doesn't solve the problem.  I think that mpi_read doesn't free the bytes it reads ( maybe internal cache or something).

Comment: One thing you are doing is declaring that you're sending 4/8 (`sizeof(int)`) integers, when in fact you only want to send 1. The size parameter refers to how many integers to send, not their size in bytes.

Comment: E.g. this: `MPI_Send(&token,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,next,55,MPI_COMM_WORLD);` says "send 4/8 integers from the buffer beginning at token to the core given by number next".

More info about cursor and opBuffer and buffer (why is it even there?) would help solve this.

Comment: Yes, he is sending/receiving 4 integers instead of just one and effectively overwritting stack variables or corrupting the stack of the other MPI processes.

Comment: Thank you for your replies i edited my post, so there is all my code. When i use "C version" no leaks but by just changing to mpi version memory usage increase. So i think it's caused by MPI directives. 
Yes, mea culpa, i should use 1 and not sizeof(int) i'm newbie with mpi and i must code that very fast

Comment: It's no surprise that memory usage increases when run on multiple cores. But that's not the same as a memory leak! Just on a first read through, you're never freeing `header`. That's definitely going to cause at least some of your problem.